# Problem with \pgfmathsetmacro and cos

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am plotting cos(2x) with tikz and would like to draw the segments between the x-axis and the plot for x=pi-1.2 and x=pi+1.2, but the value computed by pgfmathsetmacro does not seem to be correct (the values should be equal, but it isn't even the case)

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=latex,x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.5);
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0);

    \draw [variable=\x, domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=200] plot(\x,{cos(2*\x r)});

    \foreach \x in {pi+1.2,pi-1.2}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{cos(2*\x r)};
        \draw [shift={(\x,0)}] (0,0) -- (0,\y) node[above] {\y};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image: Result of the code above]

What is my mistake here?

Comment: LaTeX is macro substituting: `2*\x` with `\x` defined to `pi+1.2` results in `2*pi+1.2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply brackets. Otherwise pgf will see things like `2*pi+1.2 r`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=latex,x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.5);
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0);

    \draw [variable=\x, domain=pi/2:3*pi/2,samples=200] plot(\x,{cos(2*\x r)});

    \foreach \x in {pi+1.2,pi-1.2}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{cos(2*(\x) r)};
        \draw [shift={(\x,0)}] (0,0) -- (0,\y) node[above] {\y};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I definitely thought I had tried that... but it seems I hadn't!